# ASP.Net MVC simple package for whitelisting html elements?

Tags: asp.net, shared-libraries, xss

In the perennial question - I have a comment form in which I want to allow some html elements.  To prevent xss I need some sort of white-listing ability.  I've been trying to find a nuget package, or anything that has an html-scrubber I can use but can't seem to find anything (there is the [Microsoft Web Protection Library](http://wpl.codeplex.com/) but according to the comments the current version is all but useless)

Surely there's a good nuget package out there to do this?

Comment: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/10/programming-is-hard-lets-go-shopping.html

Comment: @MystereMan I know I know, but this is not a core business function, just some base-level idiot-proofing. Heck, ever actually read the OWASP site on anti-xss best practices? This stuff is not trivial and every other platform out there has a library for it.

Comment: How about [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)?

Comment: @EdSF - I looked at that briefly and it looked promising but I was unable to find any actual documentation or examples on how to use it for html whitelisting. Did I miss something? It seems to be more a library for structuring html documents. That leaves a lot of work I would have to do myself.

Comment: The thing is that this is something that has got to be a requirement for 80% of web apps out there. Do we as a community still not have a library or two for the task?

Comment: I've used HTML Agility pack to scrub HTML tags from content. Here's an [example](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Examples) of how it "feels"...so based on the sample, if you wanted to scrub, it would go something like `att.Remove();`